# Получение результата выполнения getRuntime().exec()

Tags: android

У меня есть следующий код:

```
Process get = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /какой-нибудь/файл");
```

Он позволяет получить содержимое файла. Теперь вопрос - как передать это содержимое приложению? Как я понимаю, его нужно записать в строковую переменную, но каким методом приложению нужно его получить?

Comment: наверное это поможет разобраться http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741878/redirect-runtime-getruntime-exec-output-with-system-setout

Comment: и это http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html

Comment: @ArcherGodson Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.